# How to join two tables without primary key or unique key?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables named LocalVSDB and TemporaryVSDB. Both tables have the same columns:

```
  LocalVSDB: msisdn,activateDate
  TemporaryVSDB: msisdn,activateDate
```

But both tables also have duplicate rows for MSIDSN

I need to join these two tables.  My intended result looks like this:

```
    MSISDN     LocalActivateDate    TemporaryActivateDate Datediff
  60103820251    2013-12-14          2013-10-05              70
  601111000254   2013-12-14          2013-10-05              70
  601111000254   2013-12-18          2013-09-10              80
```

But, since there are duplicate MSIDSNs, I am getting duplicate rows when I join. For example there are 6 rows for certain MSISDN in each table so when I am joining I am getting total 36 rows for that MSISDN.

I am joining using the following query:

```
   SELECT t.msisdn,t.activateDate AS VSDB_Activate_Date,
          l.activateDate AS Local_Activate_Date,
          DATEDIFF(D,l.activateDate,t.activateDate) AS date_Diff
   FROM temporaryVSDB2  t
   INNER JOIN LocalVSDB  l ON t.msisdn = l.msisdn
   WHERE  t.activateDate >  l.activateDate
```

Please help me how can I get 6 rows for 6 MSISDN?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you max() or min(), top1 etc one side of the join.  Is there business rules that you are looking for?

Comment: Why would you want to return 6 rows, not one? And if the tables have exactly the same columns and (presumably) exactly the same data, why do you even need to join them? Are you trying to keep one table's data instead of another's? If so, you need to explain what the logic should be in terms of which table's data are used.

Comment: you could change your focus to the temp table and execute in your where clause where in(select l.msisdn from l where l.MSISDN = t.msisdn) You'll get 1 row per entry in the temp table and it will use the entry from the localVSDB to base the datadiff on.

Comment: Are you trying to find the nearest pair of dates and treat them as begin and end records? i.e. 6/11 in table in would find 6/12 as the closest date to itself that is not equal and treat that as it's partner?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
where  t.activateDate >  l.activateDate
```

That means one row in table one can join to all six rows in table two.  You either need to change this to an = or just get a single row from the second table based on certain criteria.

Comment: If the tables contain exactly the same data, though, then the join is pointless. I agree with you, but I also want to step back and wonder why is this join necessary at all?

Comment: @evanv There must be something different between the two tables.  He is getting the dat diff so I don't believe he can use = instead of >.  He probably needs some other filter, like getting the max record from the second table.

Comment: I agree.... but it's still not clear (to me at least) what this query is supposed to be doing...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.MSIDN, m.ActiveDate, t.ActiveDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, m.ActiveDate, t.ActiveDate) Duration
FROM LocalVSDB m
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 d.MSIDN, d.ActiveDate
    FROM TemporaryVSDB d
    WHERE d.ActiveDate > m.ActiveDate
    ORDER BY d.ActiveDate
) t
```

This would find the nearest partner record and duration (the last record will have a null partner though)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own query adding group by clause provided msidn and activateDate produce unique row.

```
    SELECT t.msisdn,t.activateDate AS VSDB_Activate_Date,
    l.activateDate AS Local_Activate_Date,
    DATEDIFF(D,l.activateDate,t.activateDate) AS date_Diff
    FROM temporaryVSDB2  t INNER JOIN LocalVSDB  l ON t.msisdn = l.msisdn
    WHERE  t.activateDate >  l.activateDate
    group by t.msisdn, t.activateDate
```